# Laravel 6 error: Target class [encrypter] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm running Laravel 6 and PHP 7.2 and I'm getting this error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException thrown with message "Target class [encrypter] does not exist."

Stacktrace:

```
#14 Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:806
#13 ReflectionException in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:804
#12 ReflectionClass:__construct in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:804
#11 Illuminate\Container\Container:build in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:682
#10 Illuminate\Container\Container:resolve in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:630
#9 Illuminate\Container\Container:make in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:768
#8 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:make in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:946
#7 Illuminate\Container\Container:resolveClass in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:874
#6 Illuminate\Container\Container:resolveDependencies in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:835
#5 Illuminate\Container\Container:build in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:682
#4 Illuminate\Container\Container:resolve in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:630
#3 Illuminate\Container\Container:make in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:768
#2 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:make in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:215
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:terminateMiddleware in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:189
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:terminate in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kiri/kiriarabia/public/index.php:60
```

Any idea what I need to fix?

Comment: Did you run  ```php artisan key:generate``` ?

Comment: Yes, im getting :   Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events) should be com  
  patible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()

Comment: do you install new Laravel or upgrade?

Comment: I installed a new version and Im migrating the directories from an existing project

Comment: copy EventServiceProvider file codes on your question

Answer (score 1):

If you have organized your class into a subfolder then check the namespace – it should include the subfolder, too.

Answer (score 0):

Copy old **encrypter** Middleware to newly created project middleware folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might get this exception when a middleware does not exist.

Let's consider the following route as example:

```php
Route::get('/products/{productId}', 'ProductController@view')
     ->middleware('some_middleware');
```

If the middleware `some_middleware` is not implemented then you will get the exception *Target class [some_middleware] does not exist*.